# How to justify elements in NAVBAR with Bootstrap4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried all the obvious things like adding nav-justified, but nothing seems to work
Is this navbar properly constructed?

```
           <nav id="NavMain" class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav nav-justified">

                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class=" nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-target="#ProductsMenu" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu a</a>
                            <div id="ProductsMenu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="a1.html">A.1</a> 
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="a2.html">A.2</a> 
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="a3.html">A.3</a> 
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="a4.html">A.4</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-target="#ServicesMenu" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu B</a>
                            <div id="ServicesMenu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="b1.html">B.1</a> 
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="b2.html">B.2</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="C.html">C</a> </li>
                        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">D</a> </li>
                        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">E</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of .nav-justified, try this :

```
<ul class="nav d-flex justify-content-between">
```

and add

```
.nav {
...
width: 100%;
}
```

To be perfected, you don't mention how you wish to equilibrate the element

Comment: I notice that it seems to work if I eliminate the <nav> and the following <div> - just using the <ul> with a class="nav". So that makes me wonder: What good is the <nav> if I can do more with just the <ul> element?

Comment: It also happened to me to substitute a nav with my own flex-box attributes, so that I had more control on he elements position. I send you this generic solutino, but in your case it seems appropriated : you can have better results controlling each element with flew-grow